# Why doesn't VSCode use alias on the auto import prompt

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

[image]

I would like `@/components/xxxxx`

I have already added the `path` and `baseUrl`

[image]

I tried to change `TypeScript › Preferences: Import Module Specifier` on `settings`, But it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has something to do with the plugins. I removed a plugin `TypeScript Importer`(Maybe this is, I can't remember clearly) yesterday. But it didn't work yesterday, And it did this morning, Maybe i have to reload VsCode.

Comment: `tsserver` guesses imports. There is an open discussion to improve prioritization because it's currently mediocre. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43352